# How to remove "@8" suffix in dll file

Tags: java

I was learning JNI recently. I wrote a native method in a Java file, and got the header file after compiling the Java file with javah.exe. Then I wrote a .cpp file and compiled it to a .dll file with code::blocks. 
I ran the Java program but got an error: [java error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsL7I.jpg).

[image]

So I opened the .dll file using DLL Export Viewer, and found that the there was a "@8" suffix in function name. [suffix @8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO2e8.jpg). I thought this was the reason why my Java file could not run normally. So does anyone know how to remove the "@8" suffix in function name?

Comment: why are you just cracking the own dll?? check if something when wrong in declaring the interfaces instead..

Comment: Show us the C++ source code. Most likely, you did something wrong with the calling convention of your `sayHello` function. It should be C-like (also called `cdecl`), not Pascal-like (also called `stdcall`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790001/jni-does-not-work-with-stdcall

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the Java code, header file and cpp file for many times. I searched many information about this error before asking, and they said it is the function name resulting in the error but dit not give the solution.

Comment: @RolandIllig I've seen the link you give and it solves my problem perfectly. I am now studying the answers to this question . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile with GCC, simply provide `--kill-at` and your problem will go way. For MSVC, se [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2481656/696632).

Comment: You provide another solution to my problem. Thank you very much!